# cannot catch stale element reference - Coffee script

Tags: selenium, coffeescript, try-catch, protractor, e2e-testing

I keep receiving the `stale element reference exception` when using the code below so I decided to add in a `try/catch` block. I am still receiving this error. Is my `try/catch` block not written properly?

```
  it 'should test cells updated correctly', ->
    try 
      element(By.css('#D6'))
      console.log('try')
    catch staleElementException
      console.log('catch')


    element(By.css('#D6')).click().then ->
      expect(element(By.css('div.gc-formula-input')).getText()).toBe 'hello'
```

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong - you know why there is `staleElementException` being thrown and you are okay with it, you just want to suppress it.

Comment: I know why, I don't want to suppress it, I want to keep trying to find the element until the exception is not received anymore. If I change the trycatch block out for a 1sec wait, I never receive the exception but I do not want explicit waits

Answer (score 1):

Put the try/catch block in a loop and wait until it stops throwing the exception. Then click on the element.

This is my first time with coffeescript and protractor, so bear with me.

```
it 'should test cells updated correctly', ->

    // Define a function to check if an element is stale
    elementIsStale = (elementToCheck) ->
            try
                // Silently exercise the element
                elementToCheck.getText
                false
            catch staleElementException
                true

    // Wait while the element is stale
    while elementIsStale(element(By.css('#D6')))
        // wait a moment - don't know how to do this in coffeescript

    // Now we're ready to click on the element
    element(By.css('#D6')).click().then ->
        expect(element(By.css('div.gc-formula-input')).getText()).toBe 'hello'
```